# Partition function for weakly interacting gases

Tags: statistical-mechanics, gas, partition-function

I'm studying the Susskind lecture on statistical mechanics. A potential energy of pairwise interactions has been defined:

$$\sum_{n>m}U(|x_n -x_m|)$$

We want to calculate the partition function, and we start by evaluating the potential energy term by considering the interaction of a single pair, through the integral of potential energy between two particles over all possible positions:

$$\int dx_1^3 dx_2^3 U(|x_1-x_2|)$$

Now,there are 2 steps,

1. Assuming that $U$ goes to zero at large distances, hold particle $1$ fixed and integrate over all possible positions of particle $2$:
   $\int dx^3 U(|x|)=U_0$
2. Integrating over the position of particle $1$ gives a factor of volume, $V$.

Conclusion:
$$\int dx_1^3 dx_2^3 U(|x_1-x_2|)=VU_0$$

I cannot understand steps 1 and 2. It looks pure magic to me. Is there a formal way to explain how the integral is broken up in two parts, why we can consider the position fixed, and why the results are equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, let us first assume that the potential $U$ has finite range: $U(|x|)=0$ whenever $|x|>R$. Then, for any $x_1$ located at a distance at least $R$ from the boundary of the vessel enclosing your system,
$$
\int_V\mathrm{d}x_2\, U(|x_1-x_2|) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\mathrm{d}y\, U(|y|) = U_0,
$$
where the first identity follows from the change of variables $y=x_2-x_1$, (which has Jacobian $1$). Then, splitting the integral over $x_1$ into two parts according to whether $x_1$ is at a distance at least $R$ from the boundary or not, we obtain
$$
\int_V\mathrm{d}x_1\int_V\mathrm{d}x_2\, U(|x_1-x_2|) = U_0 V + O(R\partial V),
$$
where the error term is of the order of the area $\partial V$ of the vessel.

The situation is entirely similar if $U$ does not have finite range (but is, of course, integrable). First, we can fix some $\epsilon>0$ and observe that there exists $R(\epsilon)$ such that
$$
\Bigl| \int_{|y|\leq R(\epsilon)}\mathrm{d}y\, U(|y|) - U_0 \Bigr| \leq \epsilon.
$$
From this, we get
$$
\int_V\mathrm{d}x_1\int_V\mathrm{d}x_2\, U(|x_1-x_2|) = U_0 V + O(\epsilon V) + O(R(\epsilon)\partial V).
$$
Letting $V\to\infty$ (say, along a sequence of cubes or other reasonable shapes) and then letting $\epsilon\to 0$, we obtain
$$
\lim_{V\to\infty} \frac1V \int_V\mathrm{d}x_1\int_V
\mathrm{d}x_2\, U(|x_1-x_2|) = U_0,
$$
which is a precise way of stating the identity.

Comment: Dear Prof. Yvan Velenik, I'd have a question regarding your answer: In e.g. *Wolfgang Nolting. Theoretical Physics 9. Fundamentals of Many-body Physics. Springer. Second Edition* chapter 2, p.45, right after equation 2.48, the last equality you've derived but without the limit for the function $e^{-\alpha |x-y|}/(|x-y|)$ is given.  Is this correct or meant to be in the limit $V\to\infty$? If you have time, I'd really appreciate if you could take a look on my related [math SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4470503/proof-of-a-simplification-of-a-class-of-double-integrals).

Comment: @JasonFunderberker I am at a conference this week. I'll try to look at that as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you in advance!

Comment: I looked at your question on Math.SE. The answer is basically the one I've given above: to make precise sense of the identity you want, divide by $V$ and let $V\to\infty$. This is necessary to get rid of $o(V)$ error terms, as explained in the answer above. In Nolting's book, he's also explicitly taking the $V\to\infty$ limit (two lines below (2.48)), although he's being very cavalier with it, since there's still a $V$ remaining in his formula after having taken the limit (in the equation preceding equation (2.49))!

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, Nolting used a limit, but before he uses an equality sign in the same line, which confused me. Do you happen to know a book/ reference where this is discussed or derived in (more) detail?