# Calculating the Second Virial Coefficient

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, integration, perturbation-theory, exchange-interaction

I have seen many different derivations of the second virial coefficient, but none of them explains how they turn a double integral into a single integral.

The second virial coefficient is:

$$
B_2=-\frac{1}{2} \int d^3q_1 d^3q_2  \ f(|\vec{q}_1-\vec{q}_2|) 
$$
with
$$
f(|\vec{q}_1-\vec{q}_2|) = e^{-\beta U(|\vec{q}_1-\vec{q}_2|)}-1
$$
being the exchange term for a interacting system in statistical physics.
Normally, most of the explanations just write $B_2$ as

$$
B_2=-\frac{V}{2} \int d^3q_{12}  \ f(q_{12})
$$

i.e. integration over the relative coordinate.

How was is this step done and why one is allowed to do it if the volume space isn't symmetric?

Comment: This is very similar to the question asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/697798). The answer there might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are typically interested in the limit of large volume. Indeed, in the thermodynamic limit, $V$ is extensive so $V\sim N$. In this limit, you would expect the boundary effects to be negligible and you are left only with this bulk contribution.

Hope this helps.